# boot_quadratic_plateau in R

Tags: r

I was doing the exercise on SoilCorr package on https://adriancorrendo.github.io/soiltestcorr/articles/quadratic_plateau_tutorial.html.
While doing the bootstrapping exercise over, I have got the following error which I couldn't figure out it. Any support and explanation, please?

```
boot_qp <- boot_quadratic_plateau(corr_df, STV, RY, n = 500) # only 500 for sake of speed
Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `model = map(...)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: boot_id = 1.
Caused by error in `force()`:
! argument "otherwise" is missing, with no default
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I have tried to load the data as.data.frame (soiltestcorr::data_test). However, it was same error.